# Seeking advice: Reason for maximum update depth exceed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks, react-apollo

I am new to React and GraphQL. Trying to update React state with GraphQL subscription feed but it generates the update depth error.

Here is the simplified code:

```
import { Subscription } from 'react-apollo';
...

function Comp() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState([]);

  const Sub = function() {
    return (
      <Subscription subscription={someStatement}>
        {
          result => setTest(...test, result.data);
          return null;
        }
      </Subscription> 
    );
  };

  const Draw = function() {
    return ( 
      <div> { test.map(x => <p>{x}</p>) } </div> 
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Sub />
      <Draw />
    <div/>
  );
};
export default Comp;
```

Regular query works fine in the app and the Subscription tag returns usable results, so I believe the problem is on the React side.

I assume the displayed code contains the source of error because commenting out the function "Sub" stops the depth error.

Answer (score 1):

You see what happens is when this part renders

```
    <Subscription subscription={someStatement}>
        {
          result => setTest(...test, result.data);
          return null;
        }
      </Subscription>
```

`setTest()` is called and state is set which causes a re-render, that re-render cause the above block to `re-render` and `setTest()` is called again and the loop goes on.

Try to fetch and `setTest()` in your `useEffect()` Hook so it does not gets stuck in that re-render loop.

useEffect like

```
  useEffect(() => {
           //idk where result obj are you getting from but it is supposed to be 
           //like this
      setTest(...test, result.data);
  }, [test] )
```

Component Like

```
 <Subscription subscription={someStatement} />
```

Comment: Gave it a shot (https://codepen.io/danninemx/pen/jOPyYMX?editors=0010) but seems I am not using useEffect correctly. 
Could you kindly elaborate?

Comment: just tell me where are you getting `result ` from and i'd make a code snippet for you.